# Problem with \sidenotes in harvard-thesis class

Tags: double-sided, marginnote, sidenotes

I am using `\sidecaption` for some of my figures in the document. I have two problems with it:

1. When I use `\LoadClass[12pt, twoside, a4paper]{book}`, with `twoside` the marginnote in`\sidecaption`does not place it in the outer margin and always keeps it on the right side overlapping the figure.
2. How do I tell `\sidecaption` to put it automatically aligned to the top of the figure?

Many thanks!

p.s. I don't want to use tufte-latex!

Comment: Welcome, where can we find the thesis class? Are you sure you are allowed to change the class file? One reason: possible license issue. Another reason: If the layout differs from the intended, the thesis office might reject your thesis.

Comment: You can find it here: https://github.com/suchow/Dissertate/tree/master/assets/schools
I think it's GPL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution I figured myself**

I solved the problem after some more try and error with `sidecap` package.

```
\RequirePackage[margincaption,outercaption,ragged,wide]{sidecap}
\sidecaptionvpos{figure}{t} 
\sidecaptionvpos{table}{t}
```

Then you can format it:

```
\captionsetup[SCfigure]{labelfont={sf,bf,footnotesize}}
```